# RewriteRule в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно добавить в файл .htaccess, для того, чтобы в том случае, если не найдена статическая страница, сайт отображал главную страницу сайта, оставляя при этом URL неизменным?

```
php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off

ErrorDocument 404 /_pages/404.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.ru$
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.site.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin$
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.site.ru/admin/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/fckeditor/(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cms/admin.php?requestoriginal=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NS,QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/admin.php$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/fckeditor/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_pages/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(swf)|(jpg)|(png)|(gif)|(css)|(js)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.htm$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_pages/%1.php [L,NS,QSA]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/admin.php$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/fckeditor/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_pages/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.php$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1.htm [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/admin.php$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cms/fckeditor/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/_pages/(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_pages/index.php [L,NS,QSA]
</IfModule>
php_flag register_globals on
php_flag apc.cache_by_default Off
```

Comment: Что значит "статическая страница"? У вас можно дописать в конец правило, которое будет работать в случае невыполнения всех остальных.

Comment: статическая, эта страница, которая представляет собой просто файл название.html, т.е. ее содержимое не генерируется общим для всех остальных страниц скриптом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в скрипте есть код, отвечающий за выдачу 404 ошибки, то можно его изменить так, чтобы он отдавал главную (ну или добавить дополнительные условия). Но лучше так не делать, а продолжать выдавать 404 ошибку, добавив на страницу, ссылку на главную, ну или еще куда-нибудь, тк у вас появится бесконечное множество дублей главной страницы. А поисковые системы недолюбливают дублирование контента.

ПС: php_flag register_globals on - очень плохая практика. Что это за cms у вас не подскажите??

Comment: cms самописная, php_flag register_globals on добавили по совету хостера после возникновения уже не помню каких ошибок

Comment: Спасибо, MDJHD. Главная задача, зачем это всё делается - получить возможность выдавать пользователю как статические (представляющие из себя отдельный файл на сервере) страницы сайта , так и динамические (генерирующиеся отдельным скриптом).

Comment: Вызывать скрипт, генерирующий динамическую страницу, в зависимости от URL (для упрощения я писала, что это главная страница) необходимо каждый раз, когда не будет найдена статическая страница.

Comment: Это что у вас типа кэширование так организовано? Я бы загонял бы эти страницы просто в БД целиком! Но если без статики ни-ни, то (не знаю, осуществимо ли это для вашего скрипта) я бы делал в таком случае что-то типа этого: Получив URI заканчивающийся на .html проверял бы с помощью file_exists($uri) наличие такого файла на сайте. Если найден отдавал бы его браузеру как есть, если нет, то разбирал бы этот адрес далее в скрипте (ну например, пытался бы найти эту страницу в БД и т.д.

Comment: нет, это не кэширование, это просто у нас часть страниц представляют из себя отдельные файлы, часть генерируются специальным скриптом. И всё это надо соединить, чтобы работало совместно.

Answer (score 1):

Выполнить задачу тем способом, которым вы описали, невозможно.
Почему? Во время редиректа по определению меняется URL сайта.
Другое дело, если вам нужно показать содержимое главной страницы...  Однако тут все зависит от того, на чем написан сайт и делается это не через .htaccess.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, мне необходимо лишь показать содержимое главной страницы сайта. Сайт на php.